# how to sanitize not found img with $sce angularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs

I get html code from API service and bind it to a div using ng-bind-html but sometimes I get images like this http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx which does not exist and I want to remove it. So, I used $sce.trustAsHtml function to remove it but it did not work.

```
<div ng-repeat="output in data">
<p ng-bing-html=$ctrl.getHtml(output)></p>
</div>
```

in my controller

```
function _getHtml(output)
{
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(output);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post an example of data in general what type of data could contains?

Comment: @Mostav "<p><font face="Tahoma"><span><br></span></font><font face="Tahoma"><span></span></font></p><p><font face="Tahoma"><span><img width="116" height="30" title="" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></span><span><br></span></font></p><font face="Tahoma"><p><span lang="SV"><font size="1"><strong>Daina</strong></font></span</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my solution for your problem:

```
<div ng-repeat="output in data">
     <p ng-bing-html="getOutputElement(output)"></p>
</div>
```

`getOutputElement` defined below:

```
$scope.getOutputElement = function (output) {
   var ele = document.createElement('div');
   ele.innerHTML = output;
   var imgName = ele.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   // If img found, then check with an http GET status code comparison with 200
   if (imgName) {
       var imgValue = imgName.getAttribute("src");
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open('GET', imgValue, false);
       request.send(null);

       if (request.status === 200) {
           // html string with img ele and url is valid -> return the string
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(output);
       }
       // html string with img ele but img url not valid -> return what you want
       // for example you can remove img element and keep other html then return string without img
       imgName.remove();
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(ele.innerHTML);
   }
   // html string without img ele
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(output);
};
```

Comment: Added an update just now to remove img from ele in case of invalid image.

Comment: I have to use $sce or $sanitize.

Comment: Check again, updated my post, it was there in the comments

Comment: Thank you but it still not what I'm looking for. I have to remove the image with $sce and its attrs.

Comment: img is a trusted element, how could you remove it using $sce? anyway the return value of the function $scope.getOutputElement will be a result of $sce.trustAsHtml and without an invalid image. Can you please give more details.

Comment: It should be something like this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/provider/$sanitizeProvider#addValidAttrs
I should add a custom attr to remove the image.